# How to change RMarkdown page margins using tufte handout class

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I would like to reduce the page margins when using the `tufte_handout` RMarkdown template. I have tried adding `geometry: margin = 20cm` to the YAML, but this doesn't seem to work. Is it possible without having to change the margins directly in the template file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `header-incudes` (top-level YAML option):

```
header-includes:
  - \geometry{margin=1in}
```